Why do some GA aircraft use bungees or torque tubes vs. cables for control surface actuation?
Why do some GA aircraft use bungees or torque tubes vs cables for control surface actuation?
I understand using cables is the most common for GA aircraft.
I understand bungees are common in gliders due to low control surface forces, the bungees being in tension and adding more control surface feedback to the pilot.
I understand torque tubes are used on faster planes. Eg. 300 mph+ to minimize control surface flutter.
Why would torque tubes be used on a "slower" plane like the Varieze?
Are these assumptions correct?

You might want to edit your title since you answer that question in your question body...

Cables are favoured when the routing between input and output is complex and long. However, if the runs are vary long, cable stretch starts to become a problem, which creates springy-ness in the control circuit, creating a rubbery feeling at the stick.
Push rods are used as an alternative when the runs are shorter. You can use push rods for longer runs by using idler bell cranks joining multiple push rods in a chain, or sliding support bushings at the push rod mid point that allows a longer push rod than an unsupported one.
Torque tubes are an alternative to push rods, but can be less rigid and can be similar to, or worse than, a cable circuit in having springy compliance (it's basically a long torsion bar, like some car suspension springs). Whereas a push rod system, if designed properly, the only compliance in the system is bearing backlash for rod ends and pivot points.
A torque tube's main attraction is packaging advantages; in something like an aileron control you can run the tube though a confined space along a wing without the need to allow for arcs of movement, at a bell crank for example. In the Varieze, a torque tube is the simplest and most compact way to control an aileron, via a small tunnel in the foam core of the wing that the torque tube operates in.
You wouldn't necessarily use a torque tube for flutter resistance in itself. A push rod aileron linkage would probably give a more rigid connection than a torque tube for the same total weight, depending on how long the assembly is. Compliance in the control circuit is a factor, but flutter resistance is mostly achieved by making sure the control surface itself has its center of gravity on or forward of the hinge line so that it can't return energy into the wing structure when the wing flexes by using mass balances (although this isn't always necessary if the structure is rigid, the speeds are low, and the control surface is light).
If the control surfaces are hydraulically driven, this doesn't apply and flutter resistance is achieved by the rigidity of the hydraulic actuator connection, often supplemented by hydraulic dampers between the structure and control surface that work like automotive shock absorbers.
A bungee is just a trimming device that tends to hold the control surface at a set point using springs that you adjust when you trim, basically applying pressure for you to set the hands-free neutral position of the stick. You could stretch a shock cord from the stick to the instrument panel and one from the stick to your seat, with the tensions set to hold the stick at position X unless you overpower them by moving the stick yourself.  Gliders use bungees for elevator trim because they do the job well enough, and eliminate the need and complexity of a tab at the control surface or an adjustable stabilizer (although some gliders, esp larger two place ones like the Blanik, do use elevator trim tabs instead of bungees).

Can you confirm my understanding that bungees are additional to control cables , not a replacement for or part of them?

When used as trim yes. They are used to apply a pull or push force, to hold the surface outside its natural trim point, so you don't have to. Linked in anywhere in the circuit. With hydraulic controls however, you might see a bungee strut installed between the cable circuit and the hydraulic actuator, so the cable  movement moves hydraulic input valve controls through the strut. In normal operation, the bungee acts as a rigid rod. If the hydraulic linkage jams, the bungee can be overpowered by the pilot so the other actuators can still operate. This has nothing to do with trim though.

Gliders use steel cables running in polyethylene tubes to have more friction in the linkage. Control forces are not an issue and the added friction helps to suppress flutter.

As I fly both an ASW 20 and a 24, and the 20 has more control friction compared to the 24, (because of the mixer mechanism?) which some pilots find objectionable but as a power pilot I find perfectly fine. The 20 has some quirks and maybe not the greatest ergonomics but has a more "solid" feeling and is effortless to maintain a pitch and roll attitude while thermalling. Some pilots don't like flying it. I love it.
